# Difference between Drupal 7 And Drupal 8 for beginners

Tags: drupal

Should developers start with Drupal 7 or 8 when they are a beginner?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2707805 
https://www.drupal.org/node/1674208

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal 7 and 8 are very different.

Drupal 8 brings in a lot more of the symfony components that arguably should have been brought in earlier.

@MilanG is completely right however, D8 is not fully mature, and many of the modules and themes that you would have used in 7 are still only in beta for 8.

In my opinion, which you choose depends on your long term plans, and why you are learning it.  If you plan to be a pro developer, learn 8.  There arent yet many D8 devs around and you could jump the game a little in that respect if you worked hard.

If you want just to play with a CMS,  you certainly wont regret going with D8, but D7 might give you more comprehensive documentation and youll know that the modules and themes are robust and well tested by the community.

One thing is clear though, is that many D7 devs are having trouble converting to D8 due to the major differences in a few areas, one being templating (D8 uses twig, D7 doesnt).

Having had experience with both, I much prefer D8, but as a senior symfony dev, I probably would find that more comfortable as its closer to what I deal with on a day to day basis.  I prefer yaml for config, I prefer twig for templating, and I much prefer how D8 honours a much more 'MVC' friendly architecture than 7 does.

At the end of the day, its all good experience and a load of fun.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7 is much more mature. It has a lot of modules in stable version. It's also less hungry for resources.

At other hand Drupal 8 will definitely replace D7 at some time. It's more modern, more OOP oriented, has better template engine, it's based on Symfony.

IMHO since you are still beginner and you'll need some time to tame CMS my suggestion is to go with Drupal 8. On other hand I think that D8 is still not fully mature and lot of modules are missing but I hope in (near) future things will change. So look at the future, you'll see Drupal 8 there. :)